# How do you access the configuration parameters needed for a configuration provider?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0

This code is usual in the startup of many .netCore apps:

```
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var configuration = builder.Build();
```

You can add any additional provider to the builder object, but you'll be able to access the configuration values only after you call builder.Build()

I would like to know what is a good approach when one of the providers requires parameters that needs to be read from the configuration. For example:

```
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddCustomProvider("value1", "value2")  //THIS
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var configuration = builder.Build();
```

As you can see, would be nice to get "value1", "value2" from config, but we need first to build the configuration.

A possible way could be to load the configuration values in 2 steps:

```
        //Step 1
        var tempBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var tempConfiguration = tempBuilder.Build();

        //Step 2
        var finalBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddConfiguration(tempConfiguration)
            .AddCustomProvider(tempConfiguration["key1"], tempConfiguration["key2"]);

        var finalConfiguration = finalBuilder.Build();
```

Seems acceptable, but would like if I'm applying something that is not needed at all, some anti-pattern or there is a better approach

Comment: `.AddCustomProvider()` has access to the `ConfigurationBuilder`. If you have to build the configuration, personally I would call `Build()` within that method, and then discard the provider at the end, so users don't have to remember to do it. I don't imagine it will have much of an impact on performance, it's only run once on startup

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson, that's a great recommendation, I finally implemented that way